# Hide li have span child withouth jquery

Tags: javascript, parent-child

I need to hide li has a span child without jquery, how can i do it?

```
<ul class="select2-results__options" role="tree" id="select2-upsell_ids-results">
  <li class="select2-results__option">first (#404)</li>
  <li class="select2-results__option" >second (#496)</li>
  <li class="select2-results__option">abc (#2482)</li>
  <li class="select2-results__option">defg (#2484)<span class="description">Size: 47</span></li>
  <li class="select2-results__option">hil (#2485)<span class="description">Size: 46,5</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, [@j08691's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240827/hide-li-have-span-child-withouth-jquery#answer-46240959) is perfectly valid and neat, and is absolutely not jQuery.

However, if @Geme doesn't like it, take a look at the code below. Trust me none of the code below contains any jQuery.

You can check if there is a `span` element inside each `li` by looping through the `childNodes` of each `li`.

If the `childNode` has a constructor of `HTMLSpanElement`, it is a `span` element.

```js
var lists = document.getElementsByClassName('select2-results__option'); // NOT JQUERY
var i = 0;
var x = 0;

// NOT JQUERY AT ALL
for (; i < lists.length; i++)
  for (; x < lists[i].childNodes.length; x++)
    if (lists[i].childNodes[x].constructor === HTMLSpanElement){
      lists[i].style.display = 'none';
      break;
    }

/* ALTERNATIVE */

// NOT JQUERY TOO
Array.prototype.forEach.call(lists, function(li){
  var child = li.childNodes,
      i = 0,
      len = child.length;
  for (; i < len; i++)
    if (child[i].constructor === HTMLSpanElement)
      li.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<ul class="select2-results__options" role="tree" id="select2-upsell_ids-results">
  <li class="select2-results__option">first (#404)</li>
  <li class="select2-results__option" >second (#496)</li>
  <li class="select2-results__option">abc (#2482)</li>
  <li class="select2-results__option">defg (#2484)<span class="description">Size: 47</span></li>
  <li class="select2-results__option">hil (#2485)<span class="description">Size: 46,5</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('li > span')` to select the elements and then loop to hide them.

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('li > span')
for (var item of items) {
  item.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<ul class="select2-results__options" role="tree" id="select2-upsell_ids-results">
  <li class="select2-results__option">first (#404)</li>
  <li class="select2-results__option">second (#496)</li>
  <li class="select2-results__option">abc (#2482)</li>
  <li class="select2-results__option">defg (#2484)<span class="description">Size: 47</span></li>
  <li class="select2-results__option">hil (#2485)<span class="description">Size: 46,5</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Geme This is plain vanilla JavaScript and has nothing to do with jQuery. What ever gave you that idea?